# Why does my Node express pm2 primary process in cluster mode never handle incoming requests?

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I am running a node express app in pm2 cluster mode. Everything is working fine, however; I have noticed that incoming connections to my express routes only ever hit the forked worker app instances and never the primary (master) process.

In the pm2 documentation (https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/) on cluster mode they say

> Under the hood, this uses the Node.js cluster module

In the "how it works" section on the Node.js website (https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works) it says

> The cluster module supports two methods of distributing incoming
> connections. The first one (and the default one on all platforms
> except Windows) is the round-robin approach, where the primary process
> listens on a port, accepts new connections and distributes them across
> the workers in a round-robin fashion, with some built-in smarts to
> avoid overloading a worker process.

Does this mean the primary process will never actually handle any incoming requests? That can't be!! That would make the entire primary process a glorified load balancer and essentially a dead weight with a bunch of code and a full CPU never really getting used.

If the above **IS** accurate does that mean that the primary process is a bottleneck for all incoming express connections?

What am I understanding incorrectly or doing wrong that the primary (master) process never actually handles any requests please?

Comment: As you alread read in pm2 docs page, yes, the master process is a load balancer / process manager. The instances forked are monitored by this master process, and this brings several advantages, like auto restart (resiliency) and it works out of the box, a fully-managed solution for us. Whats the problem with this ? I use pm2 in production for several years, handlng millions of requests by day.

Comment: @JonePolvora so I appreciate what you're saying but it doesn't make sense to me. This would mean an entire node instance is just sort of wasted. It has database connections, redis connections, makes outside 3rd party api calls, is processing internal data.. All for no reason since only the other worker instances will be handling everything. And wastes a core? I guess in the grand scale of things like you suggest it doesn't matter but I don't understand the logic behind it. Why can't the main process also handle connections?  :)

Comment: I guess you're misunderstanding the architecture. PM2 is a process that wraps the code, and create multiple instances of processes. PM2 doesn't connect with any databases etc. The instance of a clustered worker process is that executes the real work, making connections, deal with CPU tasks etc. The master process (pm2) just act as proxy, selecting the instance that will handle the next request and delegating the data. Think that is wrapper of the cluster API of node.js, but without you dealing with code to run the instances. I think it's advantage just paying a little price in terms of cpu/mem

Comment: @JonePolvora I understand the architecture.  What I'm saying is that if I pm2 monit, I see all the instances of my app 0 through N... item 0 in that list is the main process. it is an actual instance of my app. I can see it connected to the database and redis and also making 3rd part api calls.  Instance 0 of my app never handles any express calls. only instances 1 through N. Instance 0 is not pm2.

Comment: Perhaps these instances are so under load, leading pm2 algorithm ( load balancer ) to not care about distributing requests, maybe because CPU is low, memory available, not so many traffic, etc... Or something bad happeing in that instance that is not ready to responding request. Can you try to simulate a heavy load test on this app in general, or check environment variables that may cause that instance to not respond to requests ?

Answer (score 0):

After I completely removed and re installed pm2 and then re-added all my node apps back in cluster mode via cli the first instance (app 0) started receiving messages. I didn't change any code so I'm not exactly sure what the issues was. Thank you to @JonePolvora for your time with comments that lead me to troubleshoot more.

Comment: after reading again our conversations posted here, I could understand better what was your issue. You were having an issue with one of the workers that for some reason it wasn't working correctly. The instances id 0, 1, 2, 3, etc are all separated workers inside a cluster. The pm2 process doesn't make part of this list. Anyway, good that you solved your issue!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue.  For some reason sometimes you will get one instance that does not get any requests sent to it.  I.e it’s a dead weight.

The solution for me was to just restart all the instances in the cluster.

Might just be a PM2 bug.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using any reverse proxy like nginx you can configure which port to be used for handling request like this:

```
**  upstream mail_server{
            ip_hash;
            server 127.0.0.1:9888;
            #server 44.229.137.214:9000;
    }
    location /api {
                    proxy_pass http://mail_server;
            }
```

**